# How do I make append work as intended with arrays?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm having problem with this code. I think I'm doing something wrong.

```
 import numpy as np

 array = np.zeros(10)

 arrays = []

 for i in range(len(array)):
    array[i] = 1
    arrays.append(array)

 print(arrays[0])
```

I was expecting to get:[1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
But I'm getting:[1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]

That is the last array I appended to arrays, and not the first one. Why is that happening and more important what can I do to get the desired output?

Comment: Hint: how many different array are there in your code? How many arrays do you create?

Comment: Also why not using `np.eye`?

Comment: convert array to nympy array

Comment: I used a simple example to show what's happening, in reality I'm using array of matrices with values I get from data, but the problem is the same.

Comment: can you give us sample output that you are expecting?

Comment: No need to set elements of `borard_matrix` to 0, `np.zeros` did that for you.

Comment: When you modify an object - list, dictionary, `ndarray`, and append it to a list, you need to append a copy, not the object that you keep modifying.  Otherwise, all elements of the list will end up looking the same - because they are the same object.  List append does not automatically save a copy; you have to do that yourself.

Comment: Yeah .copy() worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are expecting:

```
arrays.append(array)
```

to add a COPY of your main array to the **arrays** list.  But that's not what you're doing.  You're pushing another reference to the same array each time you do:

```
arrays.append(array)
```

so at the end of your loop, you have the list **arrays** with 10 references to the same original array you created.  By then, you've set every value of that ONE ARRAY to 1. So you get that the first value in **arrays** contains an array with every value set to 1 because every array in **arrays** is that same array.

If you actually copy a new array each time into **arrays**, I bet you'll get what you expected.  To do that, change that line to:

```
arrays.append(array.copy())
```

Here's a complete version of your program with this fix.  I changed it also to print all 10 of the arrays in **arrays**:

```
def main():
    import numpy as np

    array = np.zeros(10)

    arrays = []

    for i in range(len(array)):
        array[i] = 1
        arrays.append(array.copy())

    for array in arrays:
        print(array)
```

Result:

```
[1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
[1. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
[1. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
[1. 1. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
[1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
[1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
[1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0.]
[1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 0. 0.]
[1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 0.]
[1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
```

Comment: `array` is not a list; it's a NumPy array. They look similar, but the types are very different and should not be mixed up.

Comment: Doh!  Thanks for pointing that out.  Then I showed how to fix it incorrectly, lol!  I don't know numpy.  I showed the problem, and the idea of how to fix it.  If the guy really needs a numpy array, I hope he'd be able to fix this himself.  Still...you're right...I'll amend my answer. - guess my output looking different when printed should have tipped me off.  I don't act all that bright sometimes.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

just add this change:

```
arrays.append(np.array(array))
```

Comment: You made the same mistake I did originally in my answer.  **array** isn't a list...it's a numpy array.  So here, you're changing the type of the container, not just copying it.  Like I said, I made the same mistake originally.  It took @user2357112 to point out the error of my ways.

Answer (score 0):

The actual way to do this in `numpy` is with [`np.tri()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tri.html):

```
np.tri(10)
Out[]:
array([[ 1.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       ..., 
       [ 1.,  1.,  1., ...,  1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1., ...,  1.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1., ...,  1.,  1.,  1.]])
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `array.copy()` a method defined on numpy arrays as @Steve has suggested.

> As it has been already used in one of the answer (@Steve's answer) to this problem so I choose another approach i.e. `deepcopy() function`to obtain the result.

```
import numpy as np 
from copy import deepcopy

array = np.zeros(10)
arrays = []

for i in range(len(array)):
    array[i] = 1
    arrays.append(deepcopy(array))

print(arrays)
# [array([1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]), array([1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]), array([1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]), array([1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]), array([1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]), array([1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.]), array([1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0.]), array([1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0.]), array([1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0.]), array([1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.])]

print(arrays[0])
# [1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]

print(arrays[-1])
# [1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment @tripleee . I have updated my answer. I know `array.copy()` is good choice but it is already a part of 1 answer so used `deepcopy()` to get the result.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you are looking for this , just added if condition in your code

```
import numpy as np

array = np.zeros(10)

arrays = []

for i in range(len(array)):
    if i==0:
        array[i] = 1
    arrays.append(array)

print(arrays[0])
out: [1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
```